# Entity Framework - free memory from previously loaded entities

Tags: sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

I am looking for a very fast way for releasing (detaching) parts or maybe a full objectset, without also dropping other type of objectset entities.

In our scenario we use a lot of objectsets with a main objectcontext.
Some of the tables will have a very large amount of data in the future, which we dont want to load fully in memory. Only the last year data will be loaded with the starting filter, and if the user wants he can change the filter to something else. The filtering part works easy, but if the filter loads only entities which were previously not loaded yet, the old entities will be kept in memory by objectcontext. Detaching 1-2000 entities can take 4-5 second on a very fast computer. Thats unacceptable even for me, especially that the number can and will go up to be over 40000 with just one filter change.

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't be a problem if you are using Entity Framework as it was designed to be used.

EF was designed to have short lived object contexts.  You create a context for each operation, and destroy it after the operation is done.  It's a bad idea to keep object contexts alive for extended periods of time, although not as bad with a desktop application as with a web app.

There is very little to be gained by keeping a context around for extended periods of time.

EF has no facility to remove objects from the object graph, because it's designed to destroy the context when you are done with an operation.  Destroying the context is the intended way to free memory.

Comment: +1. Basically "stop fighting entity framework". The whole "main objectcontext" is already a gross mistake.

Comment: If u use for each load operation a different context, when u have two tables which are connected, how do u counter the following problems:

Comment: equal method will say, that the other list of entites are each different than the entity u compare with from the first list; same entities will be loaded multiple times. Ex.: Place table has a connection with Country table. When Place table loads it will also load 1 country for each place item, and when u load the whole Country table for a combobox selectable list or for some other reason u get a full list loaded again.

Comment: @JózsefMikla - I don't understand what you're saying.  EF takes care of "comparing" data, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: In your scenario same table data can and will be loaded multiple times if u dont handle it yourself somehow. The same row of some table will have different references in the system, so equal will always say, that those rows are not the same! If u still dont have no clue about what i am saying, than u dont have the experience at all, sorry..

Comment: @JózsefMikla - I don't know what you're saying because you are not communicating your problem clearly.  Your comments lack vital information, and make assumptions that seem unlikely to be true.  I would expect you to notice my reputation level before hurling insults.  You will also notice I was upvoted by another member with a high reputation level.  So perhaps you should consider more clearly stating your problem rather than claiming people are inexperienced.  If you actually were experienced, you would already know what I've told you.

Comment: Look, i apologize, i am sorry that u feel upset. But let me say also, that i dont care about points and such. First show me your experience, and after that i may respect u. Second, where did i say, that i did not already know every bit of the info u wrote? It seemed to me copy paste from other stackoverflow, thats why i was asking back, to be more specific, what u couldnt be. U couldnt even answer my question. U may not have enough experiencce if u dont understand it from the small info i gave. Ask back what u dont understand and i gladly clarify each bit of it.

Comment: One more thing. I wrote to a friend of mine that i think that my question will only get your kind of answer, probably noone knows how to solve it, as most ppl use EF in the manner u already described. Let me say also that i got a lot of experience in the way i described how it works and what i feel for the biggest difference is that in my way entities will be loaded only 1 from each at any given time. There wont be any duplicates in memory. Every entity has its navigation property filled up correctly, and so on ... Using different Context will load another set of entities every time..

Comment: I dont have to reatach mostly nothing as everything is in the main context already, so i call save and its done.. Thats also a small benefit. The only problem what is not solved int he project is what i was asking in my question. I also already see two possible workarounds for it. But they are not the best. One of them would be to use a special method in the background to slowly detach unneeded entities.. The other is to seperate the last year data and older data into an active and inactive part. And inactive would be loaded readonly maybe without the use of EF on demand..

Comment: @JózsefMikla - Look, it's simple.  If you want to use Entity Framework in a way that it is explicitly designed to NOT be used, then you will have to deal with the consequences that.  You are using it in a broken way, that is not supported and is explicitly against the way it's designed to function.  If you don't like that, then either live with it, or use something else.  You *WILL* fail in the way you are trying to use it.  EF has absolutely no memory cleanup functionality because it's designed to be destroyed right away after use.  I'm not going to enable you to write broken software.